# How to compare two responses in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in the database, **questions** and **user_answers** both, have the *questionId* field. I want to compare if a user has answered all the questions in **questions**. Every time a user answers a question, a new row is added to the **user_answers** table, with the *userId* of their account and the *questionId* of the question they just answered. I have thought about comparing if all the *questionId* of the **questions** table have been answered by the user *userId* in the **user_answers** table. I hope I have explained the concept well.

I have thought about making a query to the **questions** table and that it returns an array with all the *questionId*, and making another query to the **user_answers** table with all the *questionId* associated with the user *userId*, the one that is logged in at that moment.

I tried to do something, but I don't know how to continue:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'connection.php';
include 'URLS.php';

$question_sql = "SELECT questionId FROM questions;";
$question_result = mysqli_query($connection, $question_sql);
$question_row = mysqli_fetch_array($pregunta_result);

$answer_sql = "SELECT questionId FROM user_answers WHERE userId = `$_SESSION['userId']`";
$answer_result = mysqli_query($connection, $answer_sql);
$answer_row = mysqli_fetch_array($answer_result);
?>
```

I don't know how to get an array with all the *questionId*, sorry I'm quite new to php. If anyone can think of a better method than comparing the two arrays, I would appreciate it.

I was going to ask this in another post, but since it is a short question... Once I have the two arrays, how can I compare which is the *questionId* that the user has not answered?, For example, if the *questionId* of **question** are `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and the *userId* `1` has answered the `[2, 4, 5]`, how could it save in another array `[1, 3]`? Maybe with `array_diff()`?

Sorry for asking this long question, but I'm a little desperate. Thanks in advance.

## Example

**questions table**

`question_id`: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] (Each number is a different question)

**users_answers table**

`user_id`: [247] (User logged in)

`question_id`: [1, 3, 5, 6] (Questions answered by the user)

*Each number in the array is a different row*

So, I want to get something like `$unanswered_questions = [2, 4, 7]`

## Database Images

**questions table**

(Sorry, the questions are in spanish, but the important thing is the questionId)

[questions table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNuk4.png)

[user_answers table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhAPA.png)

For example, userId 1 responded the questions 1, 2 and 3, and he needs to respond the questions 5 and 6. How can I get the questionId that he needs to respond?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the values in the array you want ?

Comment: @MelvynMarigny Done :)

Answer (score -1):

I figured out how to get the unanswered questions from userId 1, it's quite simple:

```
SELECT questionId FROM questions EXCEPT SELECT questionId FROM user_answers;
```